# "This Page requires AC_RunActiveContent.js"

Tags: archive.org

I get this error message when I'm trying to access this website:

http://web.archive.org/web/20101014174627/http://certainteed.com/pdf/cside/wb008.pdf

I downloaded files from here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/activecontent/articles/devletter.html but I do not know where these files should be copied or what so ever.

Any takers on this one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are viewing pages on the Wayback Machine there's a good chance that they don't have all the files for a particular version of a site.

In this case, they might, but as it's Javascript they might not allow it to run.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the `AC_RunActiveContent.js` file needs to be deployed on to the hosting web server rather than the client.

I would contact the site in question and report the error to them.